# Question about zeros of partial sums of Taylor series of Riemann xi-function

Tags: taylor-expansion, roots, riemann-zeta

Consider the entire function  $ \psi(z) $ whose Taylor series about 1/2   "looking like"  the [Riemann xi-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Xi-Function.html) $ \xi(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}(z-1/2)^{2n} $, but with different  coefficients $a\psi_{2n}$. It is intuitively clear that one can choose these coefficients so that *all partial sums* of the Taylor series of this function would have zeros *only with the real part of  1/2*  (for example, one can choose $a\psi_{2n} \sim exp(-n^2)$). Is it also intuitively clear that all the zeros *of the function itself $ \psi(z) $* will also lie on the straight line $x=1/2$? Or it is not obvious? I would like to clarify this question.

Comment: I don't understand. Assuming the RH (and say that all the zeros are simple) you are asking if there are some simple ways to perturb the Taylor series coefficients of $\xi$ at $1/2$ such that the obtained entire functions still have their zeros on $\Re(s) = 1/2$ ? At first $\xi_n \to \xi$ is only a locally uniform convergence, if the $\xi_n(1/2+it)$ are real and even then there is $R_n \to \infty$ such that their zeros on $|s| \le R_n$ are on $\Re(s)=1/2$ and they converge to the zeros of $\xi$.

Comment: @reuns, I claim that such function $\xi$(not Riemann  $\xi$, I identified it as $\psi$) will have zeros *only* on $\Re(s)=1/2$

Comment: You didn't define any function...

Comment: I defined function $\psi= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a\psi_{2n}(z-1/2)^{2n}$ with coefficiens $a\psi_{2n} \sim e^{-n^2}$

Comment: My statement (possibly false) that there exists entire function, all  zeros of its partial Taylor sums are completely real. In any case, such a function can be constructed. Perhaps the example with $e^{-n^2}$ is incorrect, but somehow I tried experimentally to check its zeros,approximately at such a sharp decrease in the coefficients with $n$ all the roots were still real for quite high $N$

Comment: What you want is called Polya-Jensen program. See ref. "Jensen polynomials for the Riemann zeta function and other sequences" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07321) and references therein.  There also exists another approach: Polya-Hurwitz approach. See the ref. "On the zeros ofRiemann Xi function" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08868)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_N(z) = \sum_{n=0}^N c_n z^n$ with $c_n $ real, if its $N$ zeros $a_{N,1},\ldots,a_{N,N}$ are real and simple there is $r_{N+1} \le 1$ such that for any $c_{N+1}\in [- r_{N+1},r_{N+1}]$,  $f_{N+1}(z) = c_{N+1} z^{N+1}+f_N(z)$ has sign changes and $f_{N+1}'(z)$ stays of constant sign near $a_{N,j}$, so that $a_{N+1,j} \approx a_{N,j}$ is real and simple.

The $N+1$-th zero of $f_{N+1}$ is simple and it can't be complex since complex zeros come by pair.

Letting $c_0 = 1$ and $c_{N+1} = \min(r_{N+1}, e^{-N^2})$ yields an entire function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ whose zeros are all real and whose every partial sums have only real zeros.

It is not obvious to check if $(e^{-n^2})$ decreases fast enough for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2} z^n$ to be in that class.

Comment: I was rong with $e^{-n^2}$, for $N\geq14$ it has complex zeros